# Javascript is deleting the row above the row to be deleted

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, delete-row

I am writing a simple program to delete table rows on click of a button. But the code is always deleting the row that is above the row that needs to be deleted. Please help.

Here is the code:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function deleteRow(){

    var rows = document.getElementsByName("chkBox");
    alert('rows: '+rows.length);
    for(var row=0;row<rows.length;row++){

        //alert("element id is"+rows[row].id);
        var rowToDelete = rows[row];
        var toBeDelete = rowToDelete.checked;
        //alert("element value is: "+toBeDelete);
        if(toBeDelete == true){
        alert("row id is: "+rowToDelete.parentNode.parentNode.id);
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(rowToDelete.parentNode.parentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr id="1">
  <td>Row 1</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" id="chkBox_1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
  <td>Row 2</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" id="chkBox_2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="3">
  <td>Row 3</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" id="chkBox_3"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button value="Delete" name="Delete" onClick="deleteRow()">Delete</Button>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmHjK/)**

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass an index to deleteRow.
[deleteRow - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.deleteRow)

I think this is what your line should be:

```
   document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(row);
```